# How to get the best value out of gold and gems in MTG Arena?

Tags: mtg-arena

I'm grinding MTG Arena pretty hard and managed to get my hands on 2-3 top tier decks by now (while still holding some wildcards).

Up to now i just played Ranked Games to get the daily challenges done. Once I have 5k Gold I play drafts. Traditional drafts seem pretty risky to me since you have to pay a lot of gems while getting a low base-value (3 boosters)

But I haven't figured out yet if it would be better to solely play Constructed events and then buy packs with the acquired gold.

What is the best approach to get the largest cardbase with no in-game purchases assuming a winrate of 50% across all event-types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hall of Famer Frank Karsten wrote the [definitive analysis](https://strategy.channelfireball.com/all-strategy/mtg/channelmagic-articles/whats-the-best-mtg-arena-event-for-expected-value-and-can-you-go-infinite/) for this.

The short version of it is, for beginners with <44% win rate, play BO1 draft for gem entry and BO1 constructed for gold entry. For average players with 44-54% win rate, play Sealed for gem entry and either BO1 or BO3 constructed for gold entry. For veterans with >54% win rate, play BO3 draft for gem entry and BO3 constructed for gold entry.

Comment: Note that this answer may be slightly out of date.  Arena has added Premier drafts where draft against other people, and I don't know if the reward balance of the other formats is  the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

### Play during a new set's release

This is only anecdotal, but I've noticed greater success in Draft and Sealed during the first week or so of a new set's release.  Thinking logically, this makes sense - Releases are popular, and the time when the most players will be playing.  So the percentage of players who play infrequently is higher, and you're more likely to play against inexperienced players.

Comment: Back when I played, there's a promo code during a new set's release that gives 3 boosters of that set. They were typically like "Play M20" or similar, I would Google for the exact code.

Comment: This will also only work at the beginning of a new season. Since your limited-rank depends on how many games you play (and of course your win/lose ratio), you will get matched with similarly skilled players.